# I dont understand how to use the open hardware monitor source code

Tags: c#

I added to the reference the OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll

Now I added in my code: using `OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;`.

Then I did in the top form level: Isensor Sensor;

But I can't "new" it i cant create an instance of it and I'm getting null exception on it in the constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ISensor Sensor;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string t = Sensor.Name;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware

I tried ot look in the source code in the code.google.com site: http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2F0.3.2%2FWMI

But i dont want to use all this code. I downloaded the program Open Hardware Monitor and except the exe file there is a dll file im using now in my project i was sure i can use the dll to use it easier. All i want for now is to get the temperature of the video card gpu.

Comment: I know this is the obvious, but are you sure your code library contains a definition for that interface?

Comment: Shark im not sure. But the Isensor exist. Its not logical to download/copy all the source code from the code.google site, if so why have they put the openhwardwaremonitorlib.dll with the program ? I dont know.

Comment: In addition to my answer, you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843244/how-to-read-gpu-graphic-card-temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't `new` interfaces.  You can only `new` concrete classes.

Second, I recommend renaming your variable from `Sensor` to `sensor`, or `_sensor`, or something along these lines.  There is a `Sensor` class.  It's best to avoid confusion.

What I did was downloaded the DLL and opened it up in [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).  Let's see what classes implement this interface.  I urge you to download ILSpy and try this out for yourself.

Here's the resulting [ILSpy window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j46zZ.png).  Now in the bottom right I had done an "Analyze" on the interface to see where it is exposed.  There don't appear to be any factory methods that return an `ISensor`.

Back over on the left side, we see that one class implements `ISensor`: the `Sensor` class.  This class has four constructors.  These will come up in intellisense in Visual Studio, or if you navigate to the `Sensor` class in ILSpy you can see the constructors.

What you'll end up needing to do is `sensor = new Sensor(...);`  As for which constructor you use... that's up to you.

Comment: My goal in answering this question wasn't to give you a fish, but to teach you how to fish yourself.  You know the proverb: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."  With ILSpy on your tool belt, you can probably figure out everything you need.

Comment: Oh, and open both the DLL and the OpenHardwareMonitor.EXE file.  Then if you run an analyze on the interface, you can see where it's used in the executable.  I got the executable and DLL from [here](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/).  You can see how its used, thus enabling you to do what they did!

Comment: Inuyasha I used the ULSpy and i did analyze on the Sensor class and i see that the Sensor class is coming from the OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Sensor but when i added the OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll as reference and then did using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware; on the top class level i cant see Sensor i mean in the area before the constructor where i declare variables i type: Sensor and i see Isensor but i cant see Sensor. I dont understand the class Sensor should be show up ? Its part of the Hardware no ?

Comment: I see now that IParameter is containing the class Sensor. So for example if i declared: IParameter sensor; and then in the constructor i need to make sensor = ? I cant create instance ofcourse but if for example i want to get the Sensor.Name ? For example in the constructor: string t = sensor.Sensor.Name; and yet sensor is in green and its all the time null. sensor is never assigned. For the simplest thing lets say i want to get the Sensor.Name

Comment: Where from is sensor = new Sensor(...); The onyl Sensor class i found is under IParameter interface. sensor i understand its the ISensor sensor; i did. But where is new Sensor ? Cant find it only under IParameter.